# Python Pandas: How I can determine the distribution of my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

This is my dataset with two columns of NS and count.

```
    NS                                                count
0   ns18.dnsdhs.com.                                  1494
1   ns0.relaix.net.                                   1835
2   ns2.techlineindia.com.                            383
3   ns2.microwebsys.com.                              1263
4   ns2.holy-grail-body-transformation-program.com.   1
5   ns2.chavano.com.                                  1
6   ns1.x10host.ml.                                   17
7   ns1.amwebaz.info.                                 48
8   ns2.guacirachocolates.com.br.                     1
9   ns1.clicktodollars.com.                           2
```

Now I would like to see how many NSs have the same count by plotting it. My own guess is that I can use histogram to see that but I am not sure how. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think a histogram is what you want, they are for showing the distribution of data along a continuous variable - you just have 10 different name servers. A bar chart is used for plotting frequencies of different categories. Have you tried that?

Comment: @will No I have not. But I guess I Have to count the number of NS server that have the same count right?

Comment: You can plot using `df.plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @Mee Okay, i don't think i understood what you wanted to plot - i did not realise the dataframe was larger than what you have there.

Answer (score 9):

From your comment, I'm guessing your data table is actually much longer, and you want to see the distribution of name server `counts` (whatever count is here).

I think you should just be able to do this:

```
df.hist(column="count")
```

And you'll get what you want. IF that is what you want.

pandas has decent documentation for all of it's functions though, and histograms are described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html).

If you actually want to see "how many have the same count", rather than a representation of the disribution, then you'll either need to set the `bins` kwarg to be `df["count"].max()-df["count"].min()` - or do as you said and count the number of times you get each `count` and then create a bar chart.

Maybe something like:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
for count in df["count"]:
  counts[count] += 1

print counts
```

An alternative, and cleaner approach, which i completely missed and wwii pointed out below, is just to use the standard constructor of `Counter`:

```
count_counter = Counter(df['count'])
```

Comment: Or just ```collections.Counter(df['count'])```.

Answer (score 3):

To get the the description about your distribution you can use:

```
df['NS'].value_counts().describe()
```

To plot the distribution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['NS'].value_counts().hist(bins = 20)
plt.title('Distribution')
plt.xlabel('x lable')
plt.ylabel('y lable')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Distribution of count
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
sns.distplot(Dataset['Count'])
plt.title('Count Distribution')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.